# 6800 assembly code How to edit the final character of a loop?

Tags: loops, assembly, 6800

Here is the code for my 6800 Motorola assembly. how do i get it so the last character is a
‘?’ (fills each screen location with the ‘#’ character, and end with ‘?’
character). For some reason it aint working

```
           screen   .equ $fb00

            ldx #screen

reset      ldaa #'#'

start      staa 0,x

            inx

            inca

            cpx #$ff38

            beq theend

            cmpa #'?'

            bgt reset

            bra start

theend      nop

            .end
```

Comment: _"it aint working"_ is not an adequate problem description. What is happening, exactly?

Comment: Extra comparing isn't ever going to *store* a `?` into memory.  When that `cmpa` runs, A holds `'#'`, so the compare result is a constant.  Single-step it in a debugger (for a much smaller loop bound, like `cpx #$2` so you can get to the end quickly).  Anyway, edit your original question to improve it with more of an attempt, instead of asking new questions.

Comment: @Michael everything works except the last character being '?"